# How to get a badly formed excel file into pandas dataframes

Tags: python

I have an excel file of school clubs that is very badly structured. It looks something like this:

```
ClubName    ClubID  DateFormed  Participant1    Participant2    Participant..100  
Band    123 1/1/2016    "Student ID: abc\nClub Officer: President\nStudent Name: John Smith" "Student ID: def\nStudent Name: Joe Doe"   "Student ID: ghi\nStudent Name: Sarah Jones"  
Drama   456 3/4/2015    "Student ID: xyz\nStudent Name: Mary Young" "Student ID: ghi\nClub Officer: Director\nStudent Name: Sarah Jones"
```

I want to flatten it out and put it in two separate dataframes so I can answer some basic questions about the data. I am trying to get to two dataframes like this:

ClubName ClubID DateFormed

and:

ClubID ParticipantStudentID ParticipantClubOfficer ParticipantStudentName

The first one was easy, but for the second I am struggling. I am pretty sure I'm making this way too complicated, but I have tried the following:

```
#read in data
df = pd.read_excel(studentclubs.xlsx)

#get all the columns with participant data
participant_cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Participant')]

#add the ClubID
particpant_cols.append('ClubID')

#make a df with just participant information
participants_df = df[participant_cols]

#convert it to a dictionary
data = participants_df._to_dict('records')

#iterate over my dictionary to get a list out of each excel cell
result= []  
for line in data:  
    for key in line:  
        if type(line[key]) == str:  
           result.append((line['ClubID'], line[key]))
```

Results from that look like this:

```
[('123', 'Student ID: abc\nClub Officer: President\nStudent Name: John Smith')
 ('123', 'Student ID: def\nStudent Name: John Doe')]
```

The problem is when I try to convert the blocks of student information into a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}

for x in result:
    y = x[1].split('\n')
    for a in y:
        a_split = a.split(':')
        my_dict[a_split[0]] = a_split[1].strip
```

Gives me the error IndexError: list index out of range

I am a python newbie, so this is probably the dumbest way possible to solve a problem that seems like a pretty common thing to encounter, but I haven't been able to find a way that works. I am not at all wedded to the above approach if there is a cleaner way. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you share a sample xlsx file to perform the analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code runs fine with what you gave. The error `IndexError: list index out of range` can be either here `y = x[1].split('\n')`, where `x` does not have a second element, or here `a_split[1].strip` where `a` does not contain `:` so `a.split(':')` has one element.

To avoid the error, you need to check `len` of `y` and `a_split` and decide what to do when they have only 1 element.